# AppleScript: Wait for Safari page to fully load

Tags: safari, applescript

I'm using this script for Google Chrome to pause the script until the page is fully loaded:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
        repeat until (loading of front window's tab 2 is false)
            1 + 1 --just an arbitary line
        end repeat
        loading of front window's tab 2 
    end tell
```

This don't seems to work with Safari, any equivalent?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### 1. AppleScript `source` property

You could try using *Safari*'s `source` property, which is `""` until the HTML code gets loaded into it (which can only be done once the page is loaded).  Note, however, that this doesn't necessarily imply that the page has been *rendered*:

```
tell application "Safari"
     .
     .
    repeat while document 1's source = ""
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
     .
     .
end tell
```

The `source` property is reset to `""` even between page loads/reloads.

#### 2. Reload button UI element

If you want to know that a page is loaded *and* rendered on screen, then a reliable method is to determine whether the button in the URL bar is a "reload" button (page loaded and rendered), or a "cancel" button (page still loading/rendering):

```
tell application "System Events" to repeat until exists (buttons of ¬
    UI elements of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
    process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")

    delay 0.5
end repeat
```

#### 3. JavaScript `readyState` property

If you have *Allow JavaScript from Apple Events* ticked in the *Develop* menu, then you can access the `readyState` property of the `document`:

```
tell application "Safari"
     .
     .
    tell document 1 to repeat
        do JavaScript "document.readyState"
        if the result = "complete" then exit repeat
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
     .
     .
end tell
```

The `document.readyState` JavaScript property returns one of five values:

- **`uninitialized`:** Has not started loading yet
- **`loading`:** Is loading
- **`loaded`:** Has been loaded
- **`interactive`:** Has loaded enough and the user can interact with it
- **`complete`:** Fully loaded

Comment: I tried your Javascript solution on a Facebook-page, specifically https://www.facebook.com/zuck/followers but it reports that it is loaded even when it is not (in the next step I extract some xpaths but they come up empty in spite the data is there). Any ideas why?

Comment: @d-b The issue is probably timing. The JavaScript code executes both independently and without any awareness of the AppleScript that invoked it.  Consider this scenario: a line of AppleScript opens a webpage in a new Safari tab, then the next line invokes the JavaScript code on this new tab to poll the `readyState` value, which is logged every 0.5 seconds. Any reasonable person would expect this approximate sequence of values : `{"loading", "loading", "loading", "interactive", "complete"}`.  What actually happens is: `{"complete", "complete", "loading", "loading", "interactive", "complete"}`.

Comment: _...Cont'd_ When you create a new tab, or invoke a refresh of an existing tab, there's a degree of stalling that happens between sending the Apple event and the actual loading or reloading of the webpage. It's not actually stalling—there ***is*** stuff happening, e.g. in order to (re)load a webpage, the one currently displayed must be unloaded, etc. In the scenario above, a new tab was created, which will briefly contain a blank document.  The `readyState` of a blank document is always going to be `"complete"`.

Comment: _...Cont'd_ Regarding your second issue, it's unclear exactly what you're describing without seeing your code.  But, I'm willing to bet the problem is with the types of data you're trying to send back to your AppleScript.  AppleScript is a basic language with very few data types. Apart from its specialised object classes, it really only handles data of one of the following types: `string`, `list`, `record`, `number`, and `date`. Its `date` is incompatible with JavaScripts `Date` class, but the others broadly correspond to JavaScript classes `String`, `Array`, `Object`,  and `Number`.

Comment: Thank you. That sequence is exactly what happens. Yes, I am trying to extract strings from that page but my document.evaluate, that works from the browser console, returns empty string or nothing when run from AppleScript, most likely because the page is not fully loaded.

Comment: _...Cont'd_ Those four data types are the only things you can expect to be returned from any JavaScript  code you execute on a webpage using AppleScript, also bearing in mind that, in the case of a JavaScript `Array` or `Object`, every item contained by these must also only be one of these four data types. Otherwise, it will return either `missing value` or `current application` (a placeholder for `NULL`). XPath expressions in JavaScript, along with the results of their evaluation, are not kosher with AppleScript. ☐

Comment: **PS.** Whether or not I did this intentionally when I wrote this answer originally, those three methods described are in the order of what I would say represents their reliability/effectiveness.  I'd recommend using the `source` property described in the first case, as that will be an empty string for a blank document, and for any webpage that isn't fully downloaded. While it may not be rendered at the point it registers as being loaded, that won't matter, as you can still run JS code on a page that has loaded its DOM even while it may not have fully displayed and formatted it.

Comment: I actually first use the source property and then the document.readystate, and still get the complete-loading-...-complete sequence.

Comment: @d-b I see what you mean.  It appears the same issue that I thought would be specific to JS is also at play here when using `source`.  That never used to be the case, because AppleScript commands are supposed to execute synchronously, meaning if you set the `URL` property first, and then read the `source` property, that second command shouldn't begin to execute until _after_ the `URL` property has changed.  However, I've just tested it and it _begins_ to set the `URL` property while then proceeding to read the `source`, so retrieves it for the page you're navigating away from.  How stupid.

Comment: See also this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75965645/in-javascript-how-to-determine-if-you-are-at-the-end-of-a-feed-like-some-pages - any ideas how to wait for all AJAX calls to finish?

Comment: _...Cont'd_ @d-b To work around this problem, before navigating to a new URL, navigate first away from whatever page it's on by setting the `URL` property to `"about:blank"`.  Establish a loop and `repeat until source = ""`.  Then set the `URL` again, this time to your desired destination, and now do as before, i.e. `repeat while source = ""`.

Comment: Another question: shouldn't there be "a more native" way than GUI-scripting the reload button? Something similar to how Mail.app's `background activity count` work?

Comment: @d-b Yes, I completely agree.  I loathe GUI scripting and anyone who uses it.  But the fact that there isn't a native way is an issue you need to take up with Apple's engineers or project design team. Chromium browser `tab` objects have a `loading` property, so it's absurd that Safari doesn't.  But the workaround I just mentioned will mean you don't have to resort to GUI scripting, and just stick to the `source` property.  Regarding pages with infinite scrolling...  I'll have a think about that, but AppleScript probably isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Re infinite scrolling, I guess I am looking for a JS-solution?

Comment: @d-b Yes, almost certainly a JS solution, unless the site in question provides an API to access the data you are hoping to retrieve through scraping.  An API would be ideal, because otherwise it's not a straight-forward problem to tackle.

Comment: Try to find the end of this page https://www.facebook.com/events/?date_filter_option=TODAY&discover_tab=CUSTOM&location_id=112825018731802&start_date=TODAY (or any other solution to scrape the basic event info (title, date) to a CSV for ALL events). I use this bookmarketlet `javascript: scrollnum = 0; number = prompt("Number:");  function scroll10() {     window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);     scrollnum++;     if (scrollnum < number) {         setTimeout(scroll10, 3000)     } }; scroll10(); Console.log(":)");`

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with the "reload button" method as well, and [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/418604/9058) didn't fix it. Turns out if you've got extensions that add icons to the toolbar, the "group 2" needs to be changed to a different number. Because I've got a lot going in the toolbar, I've got the reload button in group 7.

To find out which group your reload button is in, run this script, incrementing the group number each time. One of the results will have "Reload this page" in it. That's the one to use.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        accessibility description of every button of group 7 of toolbar 1 of front window
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I assume this refers to https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/418604/9058 ? Might work better as an edit to that answer, actually.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realise that was possible. Thanks. I'll know for next time.

Comment: You still can do the edit, actually :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the accepted answer "2. Reload button UI element" did not work for me, but here is what did:

```
-- Safari Version 14.0.3 (15610.4.3.1.7, 15610)


tell application "Safari"
    --activate
    make new document with properties ¬
        {URL:"https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343624/applescript-wait-for-page-fully-loaded"}
end tell


tell application ¬
    "System Events" to tell process ¬
    "Safari" to tell group 2 of toolbar 1 of front window to ¬
    repeat until exists (first button where its accessibility description = "Reload this page")
        delay 0.5
    end repeat

-- Additional code as needed goes here:
```

Comment: user3439894 The script in the accepted answer "2. Reload button UI element" did not work for me. The script runs without throwing an error; but fails to recognize the existence of the "Reload this page" button and never exits. I have no doubt that the script once worked, however, there have been 2 version updates to Safari since that script was posted and stuff happens. I shared my answer not because it was the best to be had but because it does work and might help someone along.